# Client-server architecture with box2d

Tags: box2d, networking, client-server

I am running a client-server architecture with an authoritative server running box2d and the client running box2d as well.

If gravity is set to 0, is there any point to linear interpolation and creating the 100ms buffer to smooth client positioning if the forces and impulses of world objects are sent out with each snapshot (say 5 times a second)?

The client would be smoothly simulating with the server and remove the need for interpolation, right?

Answer (score 1):

The client and the server will go out of sync eventually, so you'll have a smoother game if you interpolate instead of simulating with the server and then correcting, but this will induce extra lag.

You cannot answer this definitely, it's up to you to decide which suits your application better.
Also your questions seems a bit lacking in terms of describing what is actually happening in your game/application.